# Applescript to open multiple tabs, execute a simple request then name them

Tags: tabs, applescript, rename

I am just learning to script and I want a solution to open 13 tabs in a single window, run this for each window with the value incrementing for each tab "telnet localhost 2001"..."telnet localhost 2013", then name each tab R1..R1, then SW1..SW4, then BB1..BB3.

This is how I can to the first and third parts but not the second.

```
tell application "Terminal"  
activate  
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using {command down}  
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}  
set custom title of tab 1 of window 1 to "R1"  
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}  
set custom title of tab 2 of window 1 to "R2"  
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}  
set custom title of tab 3 of window 1 to "R3"  
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}  
set custom title of tab 4 of window 1 to "R4"  
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}  
set custom title of tab 5 of window 1 to "R5"  
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}  
set custom title of tab 6 of window 1 to "R6"  
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}  
set custom title of tab 7 of window 1 to "SW1"  
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}  
set custom title of tab 8 of window 1 to "SW2"  
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}  
set custom title of tab 9 of window 1 to "SW3"  
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}  
set custom title of tab 10 of window 1 to "SW4"  
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}  
set custom title of tab 11 of window 1 to "BB1"  
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}  
set custom title of tab 12 of window 1 to "BB2"  
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}  
set custom title of tab 13 of window 1 to "BB3"  

end tell
```

It needs to run a sub for the values but I can deal with that after I've got it working as I want.

Can anyone help me solve my issue as adding the

```
do script ("telnet localhost 2001")
```

under each tab as it is opened fails at present?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
set shortDelay to 0.2
set tabTitles to {"R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6", "SW1", "SW2", "SW3", "SW4", "BB1", "BB2", "BB3"}

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set frontWindow to window 1
    repeat with i from 1 to 13
        if i is not 1 then
            activate
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
            delay shortDelay
        end if
        set custom title of tab i of frontWindow to (item i of tabTitles)
        set twoDigits to text -2 thru -1 of ("0" & i)
        do script ("telnet localhost 20" & twoDigits) in frontWindow
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but running that gives me two issues: 1 if Terminal is not open or open but there's no current window it stops running and the error is "Can't get Window 1.  Invalid index" or 2, if there's an open window it creates the the correct number of windows and runs the telnet command but the tab names don't change.

Comment: If I run the script I have (I'll post once I work out how) I have the same issue as your script for part 1 ONLY when terminal isn't open.  Otherwise it runs well, names the tabs but creates an additional "BB2" with no telnet run in it.

Comment: So, how can I open Terminal in applescript?

Answer (score 0):

This is my current, terrible, code but does the job.  Noting I need to open Terminal first or it errors as above, creates an additional "BB2" tab with no telnet script run and in some of the tabs the second script line is entered and some not.

If anyone can help I'd be grateful.

Cheers.

tell application "Terminal" -- the app
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using {command down}
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "telnet localhost 2001" in tab 1 of front window
    do script " " in tab 1 of front window
    do script " " in tab 1 of front window
    do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 1 of front window
    delay 0.1
    set custom title of tab 1 of window 1 to "R1"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "telnet localhost 2002" in tab 2 of front window
    do script " " in tab 2 of front window
    do script " " in tab 2 of front window
    do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 2 of front window
    do script " " in tab 2 of front window
    delay 0.1
    set custom title of tab 2 of window 1 to "R2"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "telnet localhost 2003" in tab 3 of front window
    do script " " in tab 3 of front window
    do script " " in tab 3 of front window
    do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 3 of front window
    do script " " in tab 3 of front window
    delay 0.1
    set custom title of tab 3 of window 1 to "R3"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "telnet localhost 2004" in tab 4 of front window
    do script " " in tab 4 of front window
    do script " " in tab 4 of front window
    do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 4 of front window
    do script " " in tab 4 of front window
    delay 0.1
    set custom title of tab 4 of window 1 to "R4"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "telnet localhost 2005" in tab 5 of front window
    do script " " in tab 5 of front window
    do script " " in tab 5 of front window
    do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 5 of front window
    do script " " in tab 5 of front window
    delay 0.1
    set custom title of tab 5 of window 1 to "R5"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "telnet localhost 2006" in tab 6 of front window
    do script " " in tab 6 of front window
    do script " " in tab 6 of front window
    do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 6 of front window
    do script " " in tab 6 of front window
    delay 0.1
    set custom title of tab 6 of window 1 to "R6"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "telnet localhost 2007" in tab 7 of front window
    do script " " in tab 7 of front window
    do script " " in tab 7 of front window
    do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 7 of front window
    do script " " in tab 7 of front window
    delay 0.1
    set custom title of tab 7 of window 1 to "SW1"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "telnet localhost 2008" in tab 8 of front window
    do script " " in tab 8 of front window
    do script " " in tab 8 of front window
    do script "sh ip int bri | e un" in tab 8 of front window
    do script " " in tab 8 of front window
    delay 0.1
    set custom title of tab 8 of window 1 to "SW2"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "telnet localhost 2009" in tab 9 of front window
    do script " " in tab 9 of front window
    do script " " in tab 9 of front window
    do script "sh ip int bri | e un" in tab 9 of front window
    do script " " in tab 9 of front window
    delay 0.1
    set custom title of tab 9 of window 1 to "SW3"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "telnet localhost 2010" in tab 10 of front window
    do script " " in tab 10 of front window
    do script " " in tab 10 of front window
    do script "sh ip int bri | e un" in tab 10 of front window
    do script " " in tab 10 of front window
    delay 0.1
    set custom title of tab 10 of window 1 to "SW4"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "telnet localhost 2011" in tab 11 of front window
    do script " " in tab 11 of front window
    do script " " in tab 11 of front window
    do script "sh ip int bri | e un" in tab 11 of front window
    do script " " in tab 11 of front window
    delay 0.1
    set custom title of tab 11 of window 1 to "BB1"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "telnet localhost 2012" in tab 12 of front window
    do script " " in tab 12 of front window
    do script " " in tab 12 of front window
    do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 12 of front window
    do script " " in tab 12 of front window
    delay 0.1
    set custom title of tab 12 of window 1 to "BB2"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "telnet localhost 2013" in tab 13 of front window
    do script " " in tab 13 of front window
    do script " " in tab 13 of front window
    do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 13 of front window
    do script " " in tab 13 of front window
    delay 0.1
    set custom title of tab 13 of window 1 to "BB3"

end tell

Answer (score 0):

Since terminal needs to be open first, before running your working set up commands, just add the cmd to open up terminal first at the top, as a work around!

`tell application "Terminal"
    set newTab to do script -- create a new window with no initial command
    set current settings of newTab to settings set "Grass"
end tell`

tell application "Terminal" -- the app
activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using {command down}
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
do script "telnet localhost 2001" in tab 1 of front window
do script " " in tab 1 of front window
do script " " in tab 1 of front window
do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 1 of front window
delay 0.1
set custom title of tab 1 of window 1 to "R1"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
do script "telnet localhost 2002" in tab 2 of front window
do script " " in tab 2 of front window
do script " " in tab 2 of front window
do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 2 of front window
do script " " in tab 2 of front window
delay 0.1
set custom title of tab 2 of window 1 to "R2"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
do script "telnet localhost 2003" in tab 3 of front window
do script " " in tab 3 of front window
do script " " in tab 3 of front window
do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 3 of front window
do script " " in tab 3 of front window
delay 0.1
set custom title of tab 3 of window 1 to "R3"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
do script "telnet localhost 2004" in tab 4 of front window
do script " " in tab 4 of front window
do script " " in tab 4 of front window
do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 4 of front window
do script " " in tab 4 of front window
delay 0.1
set custom title of tab 4 of window 1 to "R4"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
do script "telnet localhost 2005" in tab 5 of front window
do script " " in tab 5 of front window
do script " " in tab 5 of front window do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 5 of front window do script " " in tab 5 of front window delay 0.1 set custom title of tab 5 of window 1 to "R5"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
do script "telnet localhost 2006" in tab 6 of front window
do script " " in tab 6 of front window
do script " " in tab 6 of front window
do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 6 of front window
do script " " in tab 6 of front window
delay 0.1
set custom title of tab 6 of window 1 to "R6"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
do script "telnet localhost 2007" in tab 7 of front window
do script " " in tab 7 of front window
do script " " in tab 7 of front window
do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 7 of front window
do script " " in tab 7 of front window
delay 0.1
set custom title of tab 7 of window 1 to "SW1"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
do script "telnet localhost 2008" in tab 8 of front window
do script " " in tab 8 of front window
do script " " in tab 8 of front window
do script "sh ip int bri | e un" in tab 8 of front window
do script " " in tab 8 of front window
delay 0.1
set custom title of tab 8 of window 1 to "SW2"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
do script "telnet localhost 2009" in tab 9 of front window
do script " " in tab 9 of front window
do script " " in tab 9 of front window
do script "sh ip int bri | e un" in tab 9 of front window
do script " " in tab 9 of front window
delay 0.1
set custom title of tab 9 of window 1 to "SW3"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
do script "telnet localhost 2010" in tab 10 of front window
do script " " in tab 10 of front window
do script " " in tab 10 of front window
do script "sh ip int bri | e un" in tab 10 of front window
do script " " in tab 10 of front window
delay 0.1
set custom title of tab 10 of window 1 to "SW4"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
do script "telnet localhost 2011" in tab 11 of front window
do script " " in tab 11 of front window
do script " " in tab 11 of front window
do script "sh ip int bri | e un" in tab 11 of front window
do script " " in tab 11 of front window
delay 0.1
set custom title of tab 11 of window 1 to "BB1"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
do script "telnet localhost 2012" in tab 12 of front window
do script " " in tab 12 of front window
do script " " in tab 12 of front window
do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 12 of front window do script " " in tab 12 of front window delay 0.1 set custom title of tab 12 of window 1 to "BB2"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
do script "telnet localhost 2013" in tab 13 of front window
do script " " in tab 13 of front window
do script " " in tab 13 of front window
do script "sh ip int bri " in tab 13 of front window
do script " " in tab 13 of front window
delay 0.1
set custom title of tab 13 of window 1 to "BB3"end tell